# Re-writing a jQuery Expression/Selector for 1.8 Sizzle

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-1.8

A little while ago I asked a question about preventing the duplicate binding of events [[here]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341307/listen-for-changes-against-an-object-in-an-array-without-nesting-event-listeners)
I am trying to update expresion for 1.8 but cant get it to work:

the original:

```
$.expr[':'].hasEvent = function(obj, idx, meta, stack) {
    return ($._data((obj), 'events') != undefined && $_.data((obj), 'events')[meta[3]] != undefined);
};
```

My failed attempt:

```
jQuery.expr[':'].hasEvent = $.expr.createPseudo(function( selector, context ) {
    return function(elem) {
        return ($._data((elem), 'events') != undefined && $_.data((elem), 'events').selector != undefined);
    }
});
```

usage:

```
$(object).not(":hasEvent(myEvent)").on("myEvent", onMyEvent);
```

This works:

```
if (!$._data((object), 'events') || !$._data((object), 'events').myEvent) {
    $(object).on("myEvent", onMyEvent);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You have typo in code: `$_.data` instead of `$._data`

2) You can't use `selector` argument as object property using dot `.` This is string, and if you want to check that object has such property name you should use brackets `obj[selector]`

So fixed code for this expression will look like following:

```
jQuery.expr[':'].hasEvent = $.expr.createPseudo(function( selector, context ) {
    return function(elem) {
        return ($._data(elem, 'events') != undefined && $._data(elem, 'events')[selector] != undefined);
    }
});
```

Working JSFiddle available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BrPZL/).

Comment: Looks good, nice fiddle.  Is there anything wrong with my usage example? It's not working for me

Comment: I've checked `.filter`, `.not` and simple selectors. Your usage example is correct. Updated fiddle with your usage example test: http://jsfiddle.net/BrPZL/1/ - everything's working.

Comment: hmm, thats interesting.  I still cant make the expr work in my program.  I wonder if its context, the "this works" example works fine inside the same click event but the expr doesnt.  Good answer eitherway

Comment: What is `object` in your program? Maybe you can create JSFiddle with issue?

Comment: its a plain old javascript object.  It triggers an event on itself when it gets a result from the server.  I'll try and put a fiddle together

Comment: Ahh... I don't think using Sizzle selectors is good for this. Its designed for DOM-objects and not JavaScript objects... Maybe you should write your own `hasEvent` method for managing objects of your class?

Comment: I'm thinking the same thing.  But its been a good learning excercise!  Thanks for all your input